# Calling Soap webservice including WSS from javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap, google-chrome-extension, ws-security

I was wondering if there would be a technical solution to calling a SOAP webservice that is using client authentication via certificates (xwss ; digital signatures over body, timestamp, binarysecuritytoken) from javascript.  This means a keystore should be available and accessible, outgoing connection should be allowed,...

Any library exists for this?  If needed a browser extension could be used?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as far as I know. Chrome extensions are very limited in what they can do.

The possible solution would be to make an extension that would do requests to web-services and then call a [native messaging host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging-host) to do XML digital signature verification in C++/C#/whatever.

For extension you will need a SOAP client in Javascript. I had to write my own implementation of SOAP client in Javascript to fulfill the task but there are some free libraries out there. See, for example, [this one](http://www.guru4.net/articoli/javascript-soap-client/en/).